# Checking If SQL Table Exists In Union Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement

How would I do this?  I am trying to run a query like the one below on my tables.  But 1st I want to check if the database exists.  I was trying to run the below syntax but it gives me a compile error of:
'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.'

```
if object_id('table1') Is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store1
UNION ALL
if object_id('table2') is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store2
UNION ALL
if object_id('table3') is not null
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store3
```

Comment: 3 inserts into a temp table then a single select

Comment: I would try to use procedure: Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict FROM store_proc('store3')

Comment: @Igos I do not follow your example?

Comment: Idea is to use function for returning data from dynamic sql. This way you can get data from any table: Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, SalesDistrict FROM GetStore('store3')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(empName varchar(100),empStoreNum varchar(100),empSales int,location varchar(20))
if object_id('table1') Is not null
insert into @temp
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store1

if object_id('table2') is not null
insert into @temp
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store2

if object_id('table3') is not null
insert into @temp
Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
FROM store3


select empName, empStoreNum, empSales,location
from @temp
```

Comment: ohh.. late by fraction of seconds  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The tables in a query need to exist.  I can think of two methods to solve your problem.  One uses temporary tables and the other dynamic SQL.  The first approach looks something like this:

```
declare @t table (empName varchar(255), empStoreNum int, empSales money);
if object_id('table1') Is not null
    insert into @t(empName, empStoreNum, empSales)
        Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
        FROM store1;

if object_id('table2') is not null
    insert into @t(empName, empStoreNum, empSales)
        Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
        FROM store2;

if object_id('table3') is not null
    insert into @t(empName, empStoreNum, empSales)
        Select empName, empStoreNum, empSales, 'East' As SalesDistrict
        FROM store3;

select *
from @t;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my example, I am executing an sql statement. It checks for database 'AdventureWorksDW2012'
if database exists, it checks for table 'DimDate'. If the table exists, a sample select stement is executed.

I am using this example as you have not provided a database name.

```
Use master
Go

if Exists(
Select * from sys.databases where name = 'AdventureWorksDW2012')
begin
    Declare @sql  varchar(max) = 
    'use [AdventureWorksDW2012]

    if Exists(
    Select 1 from sys.tables where name = ''DimDate''
    )
    begin
        Select 1
    End
    '

    Exec (@sql)
End
```

result

```
--When AdventureWorksDW2012 exists and it contains DimDate
```

[image]

Hope this helps.